# Regex pattern for strong password

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, cocoa-touch

I am developing one application related to money transaction. So in the user registration screen I want to put strong restriction for **password**  field.

Here, requirement is,

1) Password has  must be one small letter, one capital letter, one special char ***(including all types of special character.)***.

2) whitespace and number is not compulsory but if user want to enter then accept it,

3) Password length must be greater then 6 char.

Below what I did.

```
-(BOOL) isPasswordValid:(NSString *)pwd
{
    NSString *password = pwd;
    NSLog(@"Password ==> %@",pwd);
    NSString *scPattern = @"[a-z]";
    NSString *cPattern = @"[A-Z]";

    // !~`@#$%^&*-+();:={}[],\'.<>?\\/\"  
   // @"[@!%&\._;,]" 

    NSString *sPattern = @"^\\w+( +\\w+)*$";

    if ((6 <= password.length) && [self string:password matches:scPattern] && [self string:password matches:cPattern] && [self string:password matches:sPattern])
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

And I calling above function like

```
if([self isPasswordValid])
{
 /// Your password is valid;
}
else
{
/// Your password is not valid
}
```

When I am entering like **`@ Aa123#"`** but each time I am getting *`/// Your password is not valid`*

Anybody have any idea for how can I get expected result? By regex or by any other trick?

Thanks.

Comment: `spattern` will always fail on `special characters`

Comment: Yes, I tried so many patter for that but not getting result. Have you any idea for it ? Then Please share here. Thanks :)

Comment: make spattern as `^\\S+( +\\S+)*$`

Comment: You should define what special characters you want to allow.

Comment: This is probably better implemented as a series of if statements, see the answer by @iphonemaclover. Also note that requiring "one small letter, one capital letter, one special char" does not by it self make the password safer, password trying code knows these tricks. Longer passwords and vetting against a dictionary is better. Limiting the number of attempts and the minimum time between attempts is a better scheme. I have seem thousands of attempts in a few seconds.

Comment: "A programmer had a problem and decided to solve it using regex. Now he had two problems..."

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
  -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       int numberofCharacters = 0;
       BOOL lowerCaseLetter,upperCaseLetter,digit,specialCharacter = 0;
       if([textField.text length] >= 6)
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < [textfield.text length]; i++) 
          {
             unichar c = [textfield.text characterAtIndex:i];
             if(!lowerCaseLetter)
             {
               lowerCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet lowercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
             }
             if(!upperCaseLetter)
             {
               upperCaseLetter = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
             }
             if(!digit)
             {
                digit = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
             }
             if(!specialCharacter)
             {
                specialCharacter = [[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c];
             }
          }

          if(specialCharacter && digit && lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter)
          {
             //do what u want
          }
          else
          { 
             UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Please Ensure that you have at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character"
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
          }

       }
       else
       {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Please Enter at least 6 digit password"
                                                           delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the characters in the set `symbolCharacterSet`?

Comment: Its predifined in Foundation library with  NSCharacterSet.h file
for more knowlege of Regular Expression kindly go to this tutorial 
https://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/06/26/password-validation-via-regular-expression/

Comment: `NSCharacterSet.h` does not provide information on what characters are specified by `symbolCharacterSet`, that was the question in the above comment. It just seems a little dangerous if the characters are not known. What are these characters?

Comment: please check the blog mention @zaph its shows the symbol characterset.

Comment: Still missing what characters are in `symbolCharacterSet`. The blog does not provide that information.